# Rails 4 Strong Parameters : can I 'exclude' / blacklist attributes instead of permit / whitelist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm migrating a Rails 3 app to Rails 4 and I'm in the process of converting `attr_accessible` properties to strong parameters in the controller. The [API Documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) shows how to 'permit' attributes:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
end
```

However the vast majority of my attributes are mass-assignment safe. It's only a few attributes like `:account_id` and `:is_admin` that I need to blacklist.

Is it possible to blacklist attributes instead of whitelisting almost every attribute? E.g something like:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).exclude(:account_id, :is_admin)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible.
Blacklisting attributes would be a security issue, since your codebase can evolve, and other attributes, which should be blacklisted can be forgotten in the future.

Adding all your whitelisted attributes might seem like a complicated thing when implementing it.
However, it's the only way of keeping your application secure and avoiding [disturbing things](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5239).

Comment: Haha, yeah good point. Much better to forget to whitelist something than to forget to blacklist something.

Comment: There are situations where blacklisting isn't a security concern. For example, I am whitelisting everything and then I want to optionally blacklist keys later on based on various conditions. I suppose I can rewrite the whitelisting, but blacklisting would be easier.

Comment: But I guess that is out of context to the original question. Nevermind!

Answer (score 26):

I think you shouldn't really do that for reasons outlined by @Damien, but heres a solution I just found.

```
params.require(:user).except!(:account_id, :is_admin).permit!
```

This will remove `:account_id, :is_admin` from hash and permit all other parameters.
But again - this is potentially insecure.

Why this works? Because `ActionController::Parameters` inherits from `Hash`!

**Update 4th July 2016**

In Rails 5 this probably doesn't work anymore as per upgrade guide

> ActionController::Parameters No Longer Inherits from HashWithIndifferentAccess

Comment: some of us want to allow arbitrary params, for a number of non standard reasons, while i accept the notion of futureproofing, i also assume with proper documentation, this is a useful feature.

Comment: I agree with @j_mcnally. I'm using mongodb through mongoid and I need to accept dynamic attributes for most of my models so this blacklist/exclusion/mark_as_dirty strategy is a must have for making sure that the danger attributes are not mass assigned but every other possible attribute name is permitted... Thank Michael Szyndel for pointing this out.

Comment: I concur as well; this is useful in some apps where the list of attributes for which mass-assignment is dangerous (user.admin for example) is relatively small and static. Furthermore, this is helpful for certain admin-only controllers already protected from untrusted public access.

Answer (score 4):

Whitelisting is more secure.

But u can try:
In model:

```
self.permitted_params
  attribute_names - ["is_admin"]
end
```

In Controller:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(*User.permitted_params)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

[From the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-except): yes, you can, with `except`, which "returns a new ActionController::Parameters instance that filters out the given keys":

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)
params.except(:a, :b) # => <ActionController::Parameters {"c"=>3} permitted: false>
params.except(:d)     # => <ActionController::Parameters {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3} permitted: false>
```