# Strong Params + Rails4 - How do I allow not specifically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

How do I not allow a field?

Example:

**Model Realty have 15 fields**, all params is permited:

```
def realty_params
    params.require(:realty).permit! #{id: 1, status: 1, title: 'foo', ... }
end
```

Only 'status' is not allowed, helping to clear the parameters which have multiple values:

```
def realty_params
    params.require(:realty).unpermitted(:status) #{id: 1, title: 'foo', ... }
end
```

Comment: params.require(:realty).permit(*Realty.column_names.reject{|column| COLUMNS_TO_EXCLUDE.include?(column))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. This previous question covers it very clearly - [Rails 4 Strong Parameters : can I 'exclude' / blacklist attributes instead of permit / whitelist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844435/rails-4-strong-parameters-can-i-exclude-blacklist-attributes-instead-of-pe)

> Blacklisting attributes would be a security issue, since your codebase
>   can evolve, and other attributes, which should be blacklisted can be
>   forgotten in the future.